# Drawing a square on a rectangular window in opengl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am drawing a 3d cube in LWJGL 3.It renders fine with the window size being 600 * 480.It renders a perfect cube.

But if i increase the window's width to 900 while the height remains the same.
The cube have a rectangular shape.

In 640 * 480 resolution the front face of cube is :

[image]

In 900 * 480 resolution the front face of cube is :

[image]

I want to render a perfect square without it resembling a rectangle.

if required the,
The render loop is as follows :

```java
private void loop() {

GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        float x = 0.5f;
        float y = 0.5f;
        float z = 0.5f;
        float[] vertices = new float[] {
                // VO
                -x, y, z,
                // V1
                -x, -y, z,
                // V2
                x, -y, z,
                // V3
                x, y, z,
                // V4
                -x, y, -z,
                // V5
                x, y, -z,
                // V6
                -x, -y, -z,
                // V7
                x, -y, -z, };

        float[] colours = new float[] {
               0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 
             0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 
             0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
              0.5f,0.0f, 0.0f, 
             0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
              0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, };

        int[] indices = new int[] {
                // Front face
                0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2,
                // Top Face
                4, 0, 3, 5, 4, 3,
                // Right face
                3, 2, 7, 5, 3, 7,
                // Left face
                6, 1, 0, 6, 0, 4,
                // Bottom face
                2, 1, 6, 2, 6, 7,
                // Back face
                7, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, };

        RawModel model = Loader.loadRawModel(vertices, indices, colours);
        ShaderProgram shader = null;

        Transformation transformation = new Transformation();

        try {

            shader = new ShaderProgram(Utils.loadTextFile("src/shaders/vertexShader.txt"),
                    Utils.loadTextFile("src/shaders/fragmentShader.txt"));
            shader.link();
            shader.createUniform("projectionMatrix");
            shader.createUniform("worldMatrix");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        float rotation = 0;


        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

            shader.bind();

            shader.setUniform("projectionMatrix", transformation.getProjectionMatrix((float) Math.toRadians(60),
                    (float) (width / height), 0.1f, 1000f));
            shader.setUniform("worldMatrix", transformation.getWorldMatrix(new Vector3f(0, 0, -3f),
                    new Vector3f(rotation, rotation, rotation), 1));
            model.render();

            shader.unBind();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        shader.dispose();
        Loader.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: yes, the width and height have the correct size i.e for first image as : 600 * 480,and for second as : 900 * 480

Comment: in the vertex shader i write it as :  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * worldMatrix * vec4(position,1);

Comment: public void setUniform(String uniformName,Matrix4f m) {
  FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
  m.get(fb);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.get(uniformName),false,fb);
 }

Comment: `(float) (width / height)` is a classic case of screwing things up... `(float)(640/480)` yields the same `1.0f` as `(float)(900/480)`. You can also see from the screenshots that your object is not square in the `640/480` case, the error is just not at high as in the second

Comment: @ derhass .I just added f to both width and height and it worked.        I changed width and height  to 
 (float)(900f/480f).Now the cube renders as a square on both window sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Derhass the problem is solved now.The problem was that i calculated the aspect ration as :

```java
float aspectRatio = (float)(900/480);
```

which equals to **1.0f** .

But when i added f to both width and height :

```java
float aspectRatio = (float)(900f/480f);
```

It gave the right `aspectRatio` of **1.875**.

now the cube appears as  square.

[image: the cube image now :]

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of how NDCs (Normalized Device Coordinates) work. They don't take proportions of the window into account. I believe that the issue is that you don't update the values of `width` and `height` when the dimensions of the window change. All you have to do is write a framebuffer resize callback and set it with `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback()`:

```
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, (window, newWidth, newHeight) -> {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
    });
```

This sould solve the issue. Just make sure to put it before the rendering loop.

Comment: No, I do not change the window size while the program is running. I only change the windows size before running the program. First I run the program with width as 600 and then i close the program change the width to 900 and run it again

Comment: I want the cube to be rendered as a perfect square irrespective of the window size.

Comment: It shouldn’t matter. This method should work for both problems. Just make sure to store the actual window size in width and height.

Comment: @Yan.B I did put the code just before the while loop.The problem is still there